# ZSH expanded variables in [[ ... ]] do not perform globbing

Tags: zsh, wildcards, pattern-matching

I have extended_glob set in .zshrc.

this works as expected:

```
[[ "value" = [a-z]* ]] && echo "globbed"
```

Prints "globbed".

But this does not:

```
foo=[a-z]*
[[ "value" = $foo ]] && echo "globbed"
```

Doesn't print anything.
Why is that and what do I need to set, if anything, in .zshrc to make it function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `zsh` manual (with my emphasis):

> `${~spec}`
> Turn on the `GLOB_SUBST` option for the evaluation of `spec`; if the
> `~` is doubled, turn it off.  When this option is set, **the
> string resulting from the expansion will be interpreted as a
> pattern** anywhere that is possible, such as in filename expansion
> and filename generation **and pattern-matching contexts like the
> right hand side of the `=` and `!=` operators in conditions**.

This means you should be using

```bsh
foo='[a-z]*'
[[ "value" = ${~foo} ]] && echo 'matched'
```

... to explicitly allow the string in the variable `foo` to be used as a pattern.

The code above prints `matched` if the string `value` matches the pattern stored in the variable `foo`.  Note that no filename globbing is involved here.  See also [comments from Stéphane below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694724/zsh-expanded-variables-in-do-not-perform-globbing/694747#comment1313591_694747).

Comment: Maybe to clarify, there's no globbing happening there with or without `~`. globbing is the generation of a list of file names based on a pattern. Here it's just pattern matching, we're not testing whether the expansion of the `[a-z]*` glob results in one file called `value` for which we'd need something like `() [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 = value ]] $~foo(N)`

Comment: This is it. Thank you. I have actually set "globsubst" in .zshrc file so it works without ~, however it is nice to know there is ~ option so it doesn't have to be set in it.